# How to show heading based on value in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular2-forms, angular5

I am trying to change the title based on item._id .i stored item in component.
this is my html

```
<h1 mat-dialog-title>{{item._id ? "Update" : "Add"}} animal</h1>
```

below is my dialog-overview-example.ts

```
import {Component, Inject} from '@angular/core';
import {MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material';

/**
 * @title Dialog Overview
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'dialog-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['dialog-overview-example.css'],
})  
export class DialogOverviewExample {

  animal: string;
  name: string;
  item:string;

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {}

  openDialog(): void {

  item =[{"_id": "2","animal":"lion","weiht":"100"}];
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, {
      width: '250px',
      data: { name: this.name, animal: this.animal,item: this.item }
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log('The dialog was closed');
      this.animal = result;
    });
  }

}

@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-overview-example-dialog',
  templateUrl: 'dialog-overview-example-dialog.html',
})
export class DialogOverviewExampleDialog {

  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogOverviewExampleDialog>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) { }

  onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

}
```

[Demo](https://angular-oxk2ne-ndvepd.stackblitz.io)

if _id is there in item heading should show update  animal otherwise it should show Add animal in our case id already there in item so it should show update animal ..help me out

Answer (score 1):

I could see that you have defined the item inside the component as an array. So you have to use the following code in HTML

```
<h1 mat-dialog-title>{{item[0]._id ? "Update" : "Add"}} animal</h1>
```

Comment: ERROR ReferenceError: item is not defined
    at DialogOverviewExample.openDialog .getting error above error

Comment: Can you print the data object in the dialog?